# How to split a string on a single asterisk in Java, while not splitting on doubled asterisk?

Tags: java

An example string is `2**3*3**11`.

I use the following code:

```
String[] s = stz.nextToken().split("\\*");
```

The above line is not working because it is splitting into 6 parts whereas I want it to be split into 2 parts. I want it in the above style as I have to perform exponentiation on the left and right part separately.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to split on a *single* asterisk (multiplication) only.

```
String[] s = stz.nextToken().split("(?<!\\*)\\*(?!\\*)");
```

Comment: how do you split 2**3

Comment: @user3833641, `split("\\*\\*")`. You can do it on separate tokens after having split on multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refrain from using a complex regexp, you can first replace the `**` with some distinct character.

```
"2**3*3**11".replace("**","^").split("\\*");
```